# Android app crashes because of Activity layout call

Tags: android, android-activity

I modified the Android Studio BluetoothLeGatt example project by adding what I thought was an additional view call, but the app crashes when I load it onto the device.  This is the actual problem:

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

The reason its crashing is because I added this line on april 7:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //added april 7

    // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
    // selectively disable BLE-related features.
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

I added the activity_main.xml layout file to the original project and I thought I could add it through the MainActivity which in this case is DeviceScanActivity.java.  I thought I understood how AndroidManifest.xml calls the MainActivity.java and how that java calls other xml's, but this is a bit more complicated for me because its not a activity_main.xml from the start.

The complete project is here:
http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/project.html

Here is the complete logcat log:

```
04-07 18:10:08.925 11603-11603/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getFreeMemory ()J
04-07 18:10:09.240 11603-11603/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-07 18:10:09.240 11603-11603/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416ceba8)
04-07 18:10:09.252 11603-11603/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt, PID: 11603
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.DeviceScanActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2189)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5016)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                                         at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1946)
                                                                                         at com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.DeviceScanActivity.onCreate(DeviceScanActivity.java:59)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5016) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code DeviceScanActivity  is extending ListActivity. And ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen listview in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or android.R.id if it's in code)

Comment: How careless of me, it does extend ListActivity.  I understand that activity has a default layout, full screen, front and center.  Ok so I created a new view, the activity_main.xml, but I would need to call it from a different activity?

Comment: Actually ListActivity is exposes some method that deals with the listview (ex: setAdapter() method) . If you dont using ListActivity then you have to write some codes in our own Activity class for managing the listview. If you dont need a ListActivity  Use Activity class or FragmentActivity

Comment: I do want to use the ListActivity as is.  But I want the app to call a new view/activity once it has already connected

Comment: Then use ListActivity with a listview with id @android:id/list . then it will work. If my answer helped you . Please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

android:id="@android:id/list" should be missing in our activity_main.xml file

```
 <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```